# while(true), escape condition and blocking method

Tags: while-loop, blocking

I hit a problem combining the while() loop with a blocking method.  I use while(true) + escape condition(s)  for the ease of seeing.

```
while(true)
{
    //this is my blocking method 
    BlockingMethod();

    //do other things here

    //escape condition to get out of the loop
    if(escape_condition) { break; }

}
```

my concern is once the thread gets inside the while() loop, it is stuck at the blocking method, and never gets to the escape condition to get out.  How can I deal with this?

Also, I believe my code is equivalent to this, am I correct?

```
while(!escape_condition)
{
    //this is my blocking method 
    BlockingMethod();

    //do other things here

}
```

Or will the thread get stuck with the blocking method one the entrance condition is met, and never gets out? (which will require implementing the escape condition inside the loop.)

Comment: If they are equivalent or not depends upon the initial state of `escape_condition`. The first code will always invoke `BlockingMethod` at least once while the latter might never invoke it. (But .. what *is* the question again?)

Comment: but can the code get out after invoking the blocking method?  =/

Comment: Well, when the `BlockingMethod` is *done blocking* the current execution, sure. Unless threading (or other concurrency) is being used the program will execute in a nice tidy sequence ..

Comment: what about when the blocking conditions never clears?

Comment: If `BlockingMethod` *never terminates* then "the program freezes" and program execution will *not* return to the caller. If/when `BlockingMethod` returns the "do other things" will be processed including the check of the termination flag.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that BlockingMethod is something that you have no control over?  I.e., you can't change the function to take a timeout value so that it just doesn't block forever?

If not, and you don't want to freeze there then you should consider spinning the BlockingMethod() call off into a separate thread.  Then you can modify your while loop to check if the thread is still running, sleep if you need to and if it's taking too long for your situation then kill the thread and bail out.

Comment: the blocking method is either AcceptSocket() or AcceptTcpClient().  =/

Comment: Then if you don't want it to block potentially forever it needs to go into a separate thread.